# What's the differents between Activity which theme is Dialog and the class extends Dialog?

Tags: android

To show a Dialog , there are 2 ways.

1.Activity, theme is @android:style/Theme.Dialog
2.Class extends Dialog

But, what's the different?

and their advantages and disadvantages??

which situation should I use them?

Comment: There are even more ways... An example is using a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend Dialog class then you can use the Dialog as a layer over the actual Activity (the one that needs to show the Dialog). If you create an Activity that shows a Dialog then you let back the calling activity just for showing a Dialog.

I think the main difference is that one is an Activity and the other can be used as a Fragment and thus can be a layer inside another Activity.