# Show AppCompatActivity as dialog programmatically

Tags: android, dialog, android-appcompat

I would like to show an Activity (use AppCompat) as Dialog when my device is a tablet.

Here is my theme for *MyAppCompatActivity*

```
<style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

When I put directly this theme in my Manifest.xml like this, works fine :

```
<activity android:name=".MyAppCompatActivity" android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme"/>
```

But when I would like set my theme programmatically, my Activity appears as dialog but the background overlay is black (and not transparent as the first method). Here is my code :

```
public abstract class MyAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         if(isTablet)
         {
             setTheme(R.style.AppDialogTheme);
         }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is, what do you want? Light theme ? please be clear in the question.

Comment: I would like to MyAppCompatActivity show as dialog (with my AppDialogTheme)  when my device is a tablet so I must set the theme programmatically but doesn't work with the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use bellow code for changing the background color:**

```
<style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item> //Your custom background color
</style>
```

Of course, you could change the background color from your custom `my_layout` like this:

```
android:background="#FF0000"
```

---

**And you were right**, seems like that dialog appearing with dark color.But, according to ***[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ActivityAsDialog)*** docs, if you are using on `large screens`, you have to add this in `Manifest`:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge" >
```

With `AppCompat`:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge
// or
Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge
```

And something else, check this link from Android Developers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

And here is the content:

> **Public Constructors**
>
> Dialog(Context context) Creates a dialog window
>   ***that uses the default dialog theme***. Dialog(Context context, **int
>   themeResId**) ***Creates a dialog window that uses a custom dialog style***.

And honestly, I couldn't find any methods like `setTheme` for `Dialogs` there.(I'm not pretty sure, but it wasn't there).

---

**And i'm thinking about your implementation**, i think this is not a good way for creating a `dialog`.Check and try the below code for creating a `Dialog`:

```
public class MyAppCompatActivity extends Dialog
```

Instead of your codes:

```
public abstract class MyAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

I think you did that in wrong way like an `Activity`.Check the following links for creating a `dialog` also:

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I put this theme :   `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge` directly in my manifest like this `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge" >` works fine but programmatically with `Activity.setTheme(int resId)`my dialog appearing still with the dark overlay.

Comment: `<activity android:name=".MyAppCompatActivity" android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme"/>` you are using that Dialog as an activity! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032488/whats-the-differents-between-activity-which-theme-is-dialog-and-the-class-exten

Comment: My problem is not here ! When my device is a phone My Activity appears on fullscreen and when it is a tablet appears on Dialog (but is still an Activity). If i extend with a Dialog class how to use for fullscreen ?

Comment: Well, your questions needs to edit, edit it before they put it as `hold on` thread.and one thing, i've checked it again and you can use that as activity for full screen -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html So, as i heard that from your comment, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android **Your question is not clear by the way, i thought you just wanna make it light!**